# Logic behind Hasse diagram do not contain Self-Loop

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Why poset need to be antisymmetric always? I mean what is logic behind?

and Are we draw Hasse diagram with self loop always? Then how Hasse diagram maintain poset property?

Comment: The definition of partial order has three properties: reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive. So a partially ordered set (poset) has to satisfy the anti-symmetric property. With reflexivity already as part of the definition, we avoid loops at each vertex of the Hasse diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general a poset is just defined to be asymmetric as Anurag A mentioned in his comment. But why would you want that? Well poset is short for partially ordered set. So the condition of asymmetry has to be in some way sensible for a partial order. This is the case: Assume that we would not have the asymmetry condition for some relation $R$ on the set $S$. Then there could be elements $x, y \in S, x \neq y$ such that $x R y$ and $y R x$. But this is not something we want in a partially ordered set because there would be no way of knowing whether $x$ is "greater" than $y$ or whether $y$ is "greater" than $x$. The idea of having some kind of partial order is that for any two elements you can say that one is greater than the other or that they are not comparable.

As for the Hasse diagram: It is just convenient to leave out the loops. This is simply a convention which makes Hasse diagrams more practical.